# agregar una restricción en dos tablas para asegurar que los id son distintos en postgresql

Tags: postgresql, constraints

mi duda es la siguiente:

Quiero poner una restricción en dos tablas de mi base de datos para asegurar que los id de ambas tablas siempre sean distintas. Intento con el siguiente código, pero manda error.

```
ALTER TABLE persona
ADD CONSTRAINT checando
EXCLUDE USING gist
(persona.idcliente WITH =,
empresa.idcliente WITH <>);
```

También probé.

```
ALTER TABLE persona
ADD CONSTRAINT checando
check(persona.idcliente<>empresa.idcliente)
```

Ojalá que me puedan dar algún hint comunidad, gracias!

Comment: ¿Podrías dar más detalles de lo que quieres hacer? Intuyo que emprender y mantener un modelo de datos con la restricción que expones va a ser muy difícil y propenso a errores, sobre todo si maneja conexiones concurrentes en las que se insertan, actualizan, eliminan datos.

Comment: Creo que deberías replantearte el diseño de las tablas. Si dices que `persona` y `empresa` son clientes y quieres evitar que se repitan, entonces lo más lógico es que traslades las relaciones una tabla `clientes` con al menos tres columnas: `id_cliente, id_persona, id_empresa`  y que uses esa tabla para las relaciones.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que te ayudaría si utilizas la misma sequence para los campos cuyo id no quieres que se repitan. Para ello debes crear el campo id con un tipo SERIAL, ejemplo

```
CREATE TABLE personas (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   nombre VARCHAR(30)
);
```

Esto te daría una tabla con la siguiente definición

```
                                  Tabla «public.personas»
 Columna |         Tipo          |                          Modificadores
---------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------
 id      | integer               | not null valor por omisión nextval('personas_id_seq'::regclass)
 nombre  | character varying(20) |
Índices:
    "personas_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Si te fijas en el campo id tiene un modificador *nextval('personas_id_seq'::regclass)*, esto es el generador de valores para ese campo, puedes usar el mismo generador para la otra tabla, asi

```
  CREATE TABLE clientes (
     id INTEGER DEFAULT nextval('personas_id_seq'),
     nombre VARCHAR(30)
  );
```

Con esto no se repetirán los valores para los campos id

```
INSERT INTO personas VALUES(DEFAULT, 'David');
INSERT INTO clientes VALUES(DEFAULT, 'Diana');
INSERT INTO personas VALUES(DEFAULT, 'Juan');
INSERT INTO clientes VALUES(DEFAULT, 'Karen');
INSERT 0 2
INSERT 0 2

SELECT * FROM personas; SELECT * FROM clientes;

 id | nombre
----+--------
  1 | David
  3 | Juan
(2 filas)

 id | nombre
----+--------
  2 | Diana
  4 | Karen
(2 filas)
```

[Aqui la documentación de sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createsequence.html)

Answer (score 0):

Claro A.Cedano, Las tablas personas y empresas son clientes, pero necesito que tengan identificadores de cliente únicos, por lo que requiero añadir esta restricción que cheque al ingresar una persona que su id de cliente no aparece en la tabla empresa y viceversa.

Comment: Hola Ana, por favor usa la sección de comentarios para replicar a una pregunta.

Comment: Si, claro, sólo que la página no me deja responder a A. Cedano porque me pide +50 puntos de reputación.